# Environment specific arguments in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, environment-variables, ionic3

In which way are environment specific arguments being used with ionic command line interface like `ionic build android --prod --device` to make distinctions in your JavaScript/Typescript code depending on the environment, e.g. **production** and **development**?

Should I use `process.env.IONIC_ENV`? Or in which way can I query that distinction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on the tutorial of [Rob Ferguson](https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/11/22/working-with-typescript-webpack-and-ionic-3/) there are three things to do. Depending on your file structure which is completely interchangeable (`./` marks the root directory of your application).

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@env": [ "env/env" ]
    },
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**./package.json**

```
{
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map_type": "source-map",
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

**./config/webpack.config.js** *(depending on `ionic_webpack` in your `package.json`)*

```
/*
 * The webpack config exports an object that has a valid webpack configuration
 * For each environment name. By default, there are two Ionic environments:
 * "dev" and "prod". As such, the webpack.config.js exports a dictionary object
 * with "keys" for "dev" and "prod", where the value is a valid webpack configuration
 * For details on configuring webpack, see their documentation here
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 */

const path = require('path');
// If you start your building process with the flag --prod this will equal "prod" otherwise "dev"
const ENV = process.env.IONIC_ENV;

const devConfig = {
  entry: ...,
  output: {...},
  devtool: ...,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [...],
    modules: [...],
    alias: {
      // this distincts your specific environment "dev" and "prod"
      "@env": path.resolve(`./src/env/env.ts`),
    }
  },
  module: {...},
  plugins: [...],
  node: {...}
};

const prodConfig = {
  entry: ...,
  output: {...},
  devtool: ...,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [...],
    modules: [...],
    alias: {
      // this distincts your specific environment "dev" and "prod"
      "@env": path.resolve(`./src/env/env.prod.ts`),
    }
  },
  module: {...},
  plugins: [...],
  node: {...}
};

module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

### Explanation

The magic comes in with `devConfig.resolve.alias` and `prodConfig.resolve.alias`. This line of code creates an importable alias like your own modules or node modules. Now it will be possible to inject through `import { ENV } from '@env'` to any module, component, service, pipe or what ever you like.

### Note

Do not forget to create your environment specific files. In this example you will need a file structure like that one:

```
./
|   package.json
│   tsconfig.json    
│
└── config
│       webpack.config.js
│   
└── src
    │
    └── env
            env.ts        (dev environment variables)
            env.prod.ts   (prod environment variables)
```

### Example file

**./src/env/env.ts** *(by default it will be development)*

```
export const ENV = {
  production: false,
  isDebugMode: true
};
```

**./src/env/env.prod.ts**

```
export const ENV = {
  production: true,
  isDebugMode: false
};
```

Comment: @EdsKeizer packed my solution into an GitHub repository including Ionic 3 Framework: https://github.com/edskeizer/ionic-environment-starter

Comment: the code in your GitHub repo is way different then the one you posted here

Comment: @afe Could you send me a bug report on GitHub or tell me here which specification you are using? Ionic version etc. please. So I estimate you've made a fork, right?

Answer (score 0):

I get frustrated by these half-answered (with unstated assumptions) questions. Can someone simply provide the actual CLI instructions to run a build?

Is it:

```
ionic cordova platform save
ionic cordova platform add ios
cd platforms
pod install
cd ..
ionic cordova build ios
```